# How to make a search bar for a dropdown menu entry

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My model looks like this:

```
public enum NSurname
{
    JohnDoe,
    PeterSmith
}
public class RaidRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Permissions Access { get; set; }
    public Group UserOrAdmin { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public NSurname NameSurname { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public string UNCPath { get; set; }
}
```

and my current search function looks like this :

```
<form asp-controller="Raidrequests" asp-action="Index" method="get">
<p>
    Search: <input type="text" name="SearchString">
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</p>
```

This is how it looks in my controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
    {

        var requests = from m in _context.RaidRequest
                     select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            requests = requests.Where(s => s.Reason.Contains(searchString));
        }

        return View(await requests.ToListAsync());
    }
```

I can get it to work with the string Reason, UNCPath, or Department, but not with enums..
when I try to do it with enums this error appears:

> CS1929 C# does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload requires a receiver of type

Comment: first thing `Contains` is method for string data type, and you are trying to access using `enum`, which does not make any sense.
please post your code where you are trying to access `contains` method with enum.

Comment: This is all the code i have got. I'm kinda new to this. What would be the best method for enum's?

Comment: i am not clear how you want to check, so please let me explain more briefly

Comment: The thing that i want is a search bar, where you can type in a name: for example John, and it shows all the results for all of the Johns in the database. Right now i can do it only with strings, and in reason, UNCPath, or Department(which are strings) but what do i need to change to be able to search with enums?

Comment: so instead of database you want to search it from enum?

Comment: The whole of database would work also. but how to do that ?

Comment: so you want to match from db as well as from enum also ?

Comment: either way would work for me.

Comment: still i am confuse, but you can try something like below
`requests  = requests.Where(s => s.Reason.Contains(searchString) || NSurname.JohnDoe.ToString().Contains(searchString) || NSurname.PeterSmith.ToString().Contains(searchString));`

Comment: you are saying you want to check with database, then why you want to check it with database? because your enum value is alsway fixed

Comment: if you want to check in enum then what is the meaning of your data that you fetched from database? because enums are fixed

Comment: I want a search function on my list page. i want it to bring up all the results containing that name. sorry if my requests are too hard to understand.

Comment: if i am not wrong you want to match `SearchString` with enum right ?

Comment: I just want a search function for my database. SearchString is not mandatory.

Comment: so if user type something, you want to match all fields of your class and if any one of them is matched, you wants that data?

Comment: yes that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parse enum

```
requests = requests.Where(s => s.NameSurname ==(NSurname)Enum.Parse(typeof(NSurname), searchString));
```

Comment: where should i put this?

Comment: this is starting to look like what i would want, but it throws error: CS1061 'modelname' does not contain a definition for 'NSurname' and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'modelname' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: CS0019 C# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSurname' and 'object'

Comment: cast again NSurname

Comment: NICE. This works, but is it possible to make the search work just by the name, like just John ? if there are multiple johns?

Comment: you can add another parameters this just example

Comment: what kind of parameters would be needed for just part of the entry ? like for string there was contains, is there something like that for enums?

Comment: Create new object instead of enum if you don't know number of property for enum

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution.

```
public class RaidRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Access { get; set; }
    public string UserOrAdmin { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string NameSurname { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public string UNCPath { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
    {

        var requests = from m in _context.RaidRequest select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            requests = requests.Where(s => s.Reason.Contains(searchString) || s.UNCPath.Contains(searchString) || s.Department.Contains(searchString)|| s.Access.Contains(searchString)|| s.NameSurname.Contains(searchString)|| s.UserOrAdmin.Contains(searchString));
        }

        return View(await requests.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Comment: please post list of the columns you are fetching from databse

Comment: all of these: 
`public class RaidRequest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Permissions Access { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Lietotājs vai administrators")]
        public Group UserOrAdmin { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public NSurname NameSurname { get; set; }
        public string Reason { get; set; }
        public string UNCPath { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: basically everything written in the database. names, departments, resons, uncpaths, access, group.

Comment: why are you not using all fields as a string? why are you used enums or class for `Permissions , Group, NSurname`

Comment: Because i wanted to make dropdown menu for them ?

Comment: then make two different models, one for drop down and second one for list items matched with your criteria.

Comment: for now just forget drop down functionality and check my updated code which covers all fields for searching criteria.

Comment: It still doesnt search for the names :D

Comment: How can you say it is not searching, you need to check your code